# Rewrite 2 different directories with htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a tricky problem (for me at least).

I'm trying to rewrite `/` to a folder `/webroot/www`. I have some simple code and it works:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/www/ [L]
```

However at the same time if the URL starts with `components`, followed by anything else (ex. `foo`, as in `/components/foo`), and `foo` is an actual directory that exists inside `components`, I should rewrite to `/components/foo/www` instead.

How can I achieve that? I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using Apache with .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it to at least some extent:

```
RewriteEngine   On
# rewrite components/.../ -> components/.../www
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/components/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/components/.*/www"
RewriteRule "components/(.*)/" "/components/$1/www" [L]
# if the rewritten directory doesn't exist, restore 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/components/.*/www"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "components/(.*)/www" "/components/$1" [L]
RewriteRule ^$ "webroot/www" [L]
```

Comment: Hi, por. No luck unfortunately...

Maybe I could rewrite `/` to `/webroot/www`, and block everything else unless it's `/components/.*/www`...

Comment: Where does it fail for you? In my tests it works as defined.

Comment: Hi, por. I don't know, it didn't do the redirect.

Now I have this: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/components/.*/www
RewriteRule components/(.*)/ components/$1/www/ [L]

# rewrite webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/www
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/components/
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/www/$1 [L]
`

[continues...]

Comment: ...everything works, so if I go to `/` it rewrites to `/webroot/www`, if I go to `/components/Foo/` rewrites to `/components/Foo/www`, which is  good.

However, I am still able to browse directories outside `/webroot/www` and `/components/Foo/www`.

Also, I can visit `/webroot/www` and it looks the same as `/`, while it should still rewrite to `/webroot/www/webroot/www`...

Comment: So you want two additional things:
1) All other urls (other than /webroot/www and /components/.../www) to result in 404 HTTP Not found?
2) /webroot/www should also redirect like /? Is this really intended?

Comment: hi! yes, I'd only like those resources to be able via PHP includes...